# MySQL service failed to start in manual service configuration

Tags: linux, mysql

1. I downloaded and extracted MySQL generic binaries minimal version in */usr/local/mysql*.
2. I created *mysql* group in my system
3. I added current user to *mysql* group.
4. I executed:

   ```sh
   sudo chown -R user:mysql /usr/local/mysql
   sudo chmod -R 750 /usr/local/mysql
   ```
5. I added */usr/local/mysql/bin* folder to */etc/profile*
6. Restarted the system.
7. I initialized database with `mysqld --defaults-file=/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf --initialize`. Initialization was successful.
8. To install mysql service, I copied *mysql.server* service file in */etc/init.d*" folder as *mysql* and executed `update-rc.d mysql defaults`.

But when I restarted the system, *mysql* service was down. So I tried to run *mysql.server* service file from base directory with `mysql.server start` command and it executed successfully.
What is the problem? What did I miss here?

my.cnf config file:

```
[mysql]
port = 3306

[mysqld]
port = 3306
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
basedir = /usr/local/mysql
datadir = /usr/local/mysql/mysqld/data
plugin-dir = /usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin
pid-file = /usr/local/mysql/mysqld/mysqld.pid
log-error = /usr/local/mysql/mysqld/mysqld.err
```

Systemd Log:

```
Aug 31 12:08:12 inspiron systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MySQL...
Aug 31 20:58:34 inspiron mysql[6941]: Starting MySQL
Aug 31 20:58:34 inspiron mysql[6941]: /usr/local/mysql/mysqld/mysqld.pid
Aug 31 20:58:34 inspiron mysql[6941]: .2019-08-31T16:28:34.274179Z mysqld_safe error: log-error set to '/usr/local/mysql/mysqld/mysqld.err', however file don't exists. Create writable for user 'mysql'.
Aug 31 20:58:35 inspiron mysql[6941]:  * The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/mysqld/mysqld.pid).
Aug 31 20:58:35 inspiron systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 31 20:58:35 inspiron systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 31 20:58:35 inspiron systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop MySQL.
```

OS: Elementary OS (Ubuntu based)
Kernel: 4.15.0-58-generic
Init System: systemd
MySQL: 8.0.17

Comment: What's your init system? What do your MySQL logs say? What do your init system logs say?

Comment: Hi I updated my question with some information.

Comment: You're using init.d and update-rc.d with systemd which not generally recommended. You're manually staring mysql.server and automatically starting mysql. Try using systemd when testing starting the service manually instead of running scripts from your shell and expecting systemd to be setup the same.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I found official page for configuring mysql service with systemd. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-secure-deployment-guide/8.0/en/secure-deployment-post-install.html#secure-deployment-systemd-startup

Comment: Are you actually installing MySQL Enterprise Edition?

Comment: No, I am using MySQL community server.